# Fiddler proxy doesn't work for some HTTPS requests

Tags: android, https, proxy, fiddler

I want to use Fiddler to watch traffic from my phone (Android). I allowed remote computers to connect. It works... for some pages.

I can preview HTTPS requests to Google, PayPal, etc. in Fiddler. But when I try to open GitHub, I have [this message (Text View for CONNECT request)](http://scr.hu/24rj/py4ix). Same goes for Dropbox or Twitch app (these fail to connect to servers).

I cannot connect to Github from computer either (when capturing traffic with Fiddler).

How can I fix it?